# AppleScript : Download to a AFP drive

Tags: applescript, data-transfer

I try to download files to a AFP drive but always have "Warning: Failed to create the file /Volumes/home/Downloads: Is a directory
"

But the last command work fine 
    tell application "Finder" to open ("/Volumes/home/Downloads" as POSIX file)

```
set theFileURL to the clipboard
set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
set theFile to text item -1 of theFileURL
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

set theFilePath to "/Volumes/home/Downloads"
try
    do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theFileURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFilePath
    display dialog "The download is finished!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon note giving up after 5
on error theError
    display dialog "Error downloading the file:" & return & theFile & return & return & theError buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 0 giving up after 5
end try


tell application "Finder" to open ("/Volumes/home/Downloads" as POSIX file)
```

in the same kind of script, I'm also to download torrent to my Synology Download Station if anyone have a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curl` *command* in the `do shell script` *command* is malformed.  The `-o` *option* expects a *filename* or a *fully qualified pathname filename* not just a *path* like what the *variable* `theFilePath` contains.  See the man page for `curl`, in a Terminal type `man curl` and press enter and then scroll down to `-o, --output <file>` where it states: `Write output to <file> instead of stdout.`

So your `do shell script` *command* should look like:

```
do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theFileURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of (theFilePath & "/" & theFile)
```

If you include the `/` (slash) at the end of the *value* you *set* for the `theFilePath` *variable* e.g. `set theFilePath to "/Volumes/home/Downloads/"` you can eliminate `& "/"` from the `do shell script` *command*, which would then look like:

```
do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theFileURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of (theFilePath & theFile)
```

Additionally, since you have already set `theFilePath` you can use that in your `tell application "Finder"` *statement*, e.g:

```
tell application "Finder" to open theFilePath as POSIX file
```

If you want Finder to trigger the opening of the file, and depending on how you set `theFilePath` (with or without a `/`) use one of the following appropriately:

```
tell application "Finder" to open (theFilePath & "/" & theFile) as POSIX file
tell application "Finder" to open (theFilePath & theFile) as POSIX file
```

The AppleScript *code* shown below contains both forms of the `theFilePath` *variable* and the `do shell script` *command* along with two version of the `tell application "Finder"` *statement* with one set commented out with the leading `--` (double-dash).

```
set theFileURL to the clipboard
set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
set theFile to text item -1 of theFileURL
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

-- set theFilePath to "/Volumes/home/Downloads"
set theFilePath to "/Volumes/home/Downloads/"

try
    -- do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theFileURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of (theFilePath & "/" & theFile)

    do shell script "curl " & quoted form of theFileURL & " -o " & quoted form of POSIX path of (theFilePath & theFile)

    display dialog "The download is finished!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon note giving up after 5
on error theError
    display dialog "Error downloading the file:" & return & theFile & return & return & theError buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon 0 giving up after 5
end try

tell application "Finder" to open theFilePath as POSIX file
-- tell application "Finder" to open (theFilePath & "/" & theFile) as POSIX file
-- tell application "Finder" to open (theFilePath & theFile) as POSIX file
```

Comment: @KevinCork,  Sorry I left out some parentheses, in the `do shell script` _command_, so I added them to `theFilePath & theFile` and `theFilePath & "/" & theFile` e.g `(theFilePath & theFile)` and `(theFilePath & "/" & theFile)` so if the `theFile` _variable_ filename has spaces it's handled properly.

Comment: for some reason it's only downloading the first bytes of the file.

Comment: @KevinCork, Can you provide the URL so I can test it.  Also, if you use `curl` directly in a Terminal does it download only part of the file?

Comment: sure, I just testing with a random URL http://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.1/macosx/vlc-2.2.1.dmg

Comment: @KevinCork, That file bombs out for me too in both AppleScript and using `curl` in aTerminal so it's not an AppleScript issue.  Other files work for me fine.

Comment: great thank you! I should have try to download a another file first, sorry

Comment: @KevinCork, That particular URL is not a direct URL as it gets redirected to a mirror. It appears for some reason that `curl` isn't handling the redirection in this particular case however `wget` will handle it although `wget` has to be added to OS X, it's not a default utility.  What's in that bad  and truncated `vlc-2.2.1.dmg` file is actually text as in this example: `'Click <a href="http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/videolan/vlc/2.2.1/macosx/vlc-2.2.1.dmg">here</a> if not redirected.'`